# Update string JSON with mySql query

Tags: mysql, json

I have this mySql (ver 5.7.14) fields.

```
id  shop_name   json_string

 1   shop_1     [{"your_number": "2", "player_id": "6789" }, {"your_number": "3", "player_id": "9877" }, {"your_number": "4",   "player_id": "132456" }]  

 2   shop_2     [{"your_number": "2", "player_id": "6789" }, {"your_number": "3", "player_id": "9877" }, {"your_number": "4",   "player_id": "132456" }]
```

how can I update string based on id and JSON your_number?

For example I'd like remove your_number = 3 string where id = 2

Result:

```
id  shop_name   json_string
 2   shop_2     [{"your_number": "2", "player_id": "6789" }, {"your_number": "4",   "player_id": "132456" }]
```

thanks!

Comment: What did you mean update string based on id and JSON your_number? what's your mysql version?

Answer (score 1):

I tested this and it works:

```
UPDATE Shops
SET json_string = JSON_REMOVE(
  json_string, 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(json_string, 'one', '3', null, '$[*].your_number')), '.', 1)
)
WHERE id = 2;
```

I have to comment that this does NOT make JSON seem like a good idea for your application.

If you have a requirement to manipulate JSON documents, it would be easier to store your database as a normalized set of tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Shops (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  shop_name VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE ShopPlayers (
  shop_id INT NOT NULL,
  your_number INT NOT NULL,
  player_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (shop_id, your_number)
);
```

Now you can remove a player with more straightforward SQL:

```
DELETE FROM ShopPlayers WHERE shop_id = 2 AND your_number = 3;
```

I've been watching questions about mysql and json on Stack Overflow for a while, and I have to say that in virtually all cases I've seen, it would be better if the tables were designed in a traditional way, according to rules of normalization. The SQL queries would be easier to write and easier to debug, they would run faster, and the database would store the data more efficiently.

Comment: Work perfect with your code! why is not good idea working in this mode?

Comment: It's not a good idea to use JSON for cases that would simpler and more efficient if you designed them as a traditional, normalized database. For one thing, you would be able to code simple tasks like "delete one player" without posting to Stack Overflow to ask the solution.

Comment: at first I created a separate table like your example, but I wanted to experience
method with JSON mode.

Comment: How is your experience so far?

Comment: I'm studying it and I really like how it works, but operations is more difficult in this way. conversely if building a JSON file based on a normalized database is more simple. however, I will follow your advice working with traditional normalized database.

Comment: JSON can be used if you need semi-structured data, where the fields are variable and unpredictable. But if the items in your JSON always follow a consistent structure anyway, you might as well use real columns, which are easier to query, easier to index, you can use data types and constraints, etc. Try implementing `NOT NULL` for a single field in a JSON document. That's not what it's for!

Comment: Thank you very much for Help! Now I'm working with classic normalized database and creating JSON file through jQuery/Ajax method.